# Warn users that their last (link-only) answers were deleted when posting a new answer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers

I would imagine that most people who flag questions will inevitably run into the *Your last flag was declined* message.  I'd like to see this implemented for answers as well, specifically for users who have link only answers (especially to their own website [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23638465/209259), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21928894/209259), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21905219/209259), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21773059/209259), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21229064/209259), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21229031/209259)). I wouldn't imagine this would prevent someone from answering the question, but instead help users create better answers that can answer the question without external links.

Here's my very bad and extremely quick rendition of the feature:

> [image]

Comment: they say this [already is done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118/165773): "a warning to folks who are about to post a question or an answer when they already have a track record of ... suboptimal questions" (although the wording is somewhat ambiguous)

Comment: @gnat ah, I didn't find that because it was meta.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[New users whose last answer was deleted will see the following when they try to post a new one:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow/231118#231118)

[image]

In addition, if the answer was deleted from review and someone opted to leave one of the canned comments (there's one specifically related to link-only answers), the author will be notified via their global inbox, complete with a link to the deleted answer - this happens regardless of their reputation or time on the site. I've watched users respond to this by editing their existing answers, so I'm fairly confident that it works... for those who care.

Comment: Is there a specific message for link-only cases? Otherwise *this* warning is ambiguous.