# Should we have an automatic hint saying that link-only answers are discouraged?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

A significant number of the posts ending in the *Low Quality Post Queue* are there for being link-only-answers.

<sub>(At least, this has been by far the most frequent reason why I recommended deletion. There are many "low quality" answers, but for few of them a deletion is justified according to [the recent definitions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)).</sub>

There was already the request to [Warn users that their last (link-only) answers were deleted when posting a new answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268643/warn-users-that-their-last-link-only-answers-were-deleted-when-posting-a-new-a) . However, this may be "too late", because the queue will most likely be jammed by first answers that are link-only, and people can continue posting link-only-answers until their first link-only-answers are deleted and the warning appears.

I think that it should technically not be so hard to *automatically* detect whether an answer is a link-only-answer: If there are "many" links in an answer, compared to the total length, a warning could appear. "Many" could be something like "more than one (external) link per 15 words of text". Such a warning could roughly contain the text from the deletion reason:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

(which is now copied and pasted manually as a comment to many of these answers that eventually end up in the LQRQ).

This is not a feature request. I'd just like to know whether people think that such a hint could help to reduce the number of link-only-answers, and help draining the *Low Quality Post Queue*.

Comment: `This is not a feature request.` How is this not a feature request?  Saying that your request for a new feature isn't a feature request doesn't make it not a feature request.

Comment: @Servy I do not *request* this feature. First of all I'd like to know whether people think that such a feature might be helpful. If they do, one could consider *requesting* it. (Maybe I'm nitpicking or misinterpreting something here...)

Comment: That's what a feature request is.  It's proposing a feature to see what people think about it.

Comment: @Servy What he's saying is, this is not _yet_ a feature request.

Comment: @200_success What I'm saying is that it *is* a feature request.  Him saying that it's not a feature request doesn't change the fact that *it is a feature request*.  He could end his post by saying that he's not asking a question on meta.so, but that wouldn't make it not a question on meta.so.

Comment: @Marco13 If you want to have a meaningful discussion, split your post into a question and answer. The question is: "what to do about link-only answers from repeat offenders?" Then post your suggestion as a self-answer. [Example 1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244727/marking-your-own-question-obsolete), [Example 2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244134/148099)

Comment: Whether or not the question about whether a feature might be helpful can be considered as a "request" may not be entirely clear, and possibly subjective. @Servy I hope it's better now, with the changed title.

Answer (score 2):

> I think that it should technically not be so hard to automatically detect whether an answer is a link-only-answer: If there are "many" links in an answer, compared to the total length, a warning could appear. "Many" could be something like "more than one (external) link per 15 words of text".

You are correct that the auto-detection is not hard - the existing auto detection is usually the reason why the post ended up in the LQRQ (it would have been flagged by Community).

You have to consider whether showing a warning is going to be truly effective - as is already evident new users usually do not read instructions or help pages, they are going to click whatever button necessary to get their answer posted as fast as possible so they can share in the rush of magical rep points.

I think it's unlikely that showing a warning hasn't already been considered by the SE dev team, but they have chosen to go with flagging by the Community user as an all-round more effective solution. Putting a product manager hat on, I would suggest that showing a warning that can be circumvented or ignored is a waste of time especially when there is already a well oiled mechanism in place.

Comment: Sure, whether it would be effective is the core of the question. Most likely, the devs know from experience whether this will be the case. It may depend on whether the link-posters did not *read* the FAQ and "How To Answer", or are plainly *ignoring* it. In the latter case, they could also ignore any warning that pops up. But if they only did not *read* the FAQ (in their rush for the rep), then a big, red warning saying "You'll lose your magical rep points by posting only a link!" might be helpful...